# downloaded ArrayList from asynctask becomes null after finish method exection

Tags: android

I'm working on an app in which some contents to be downloaded to an ArrayList using AsyncTasks.

Problem is, after finishing execution of related method, the value of these ArrayLists returns back to null, so when I use an intent to pass it to another activity; it won't send the previously downloaded values, instead I'm having null pointer exception (I checked the contents of ArrayLists before initiating the intent and found them all become null).

The code for getting values through AsyncTask:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment
implements UpdateComponents.AsyncContentsResponse, UpdateComponents.AsyncOtherContentsResponse {

private static ArrayList<String> names;
private static ArrayList<Drawable> images;

private static ArrayList<String> someContents;
private static ArrayList<String> anotherContents;

UpdateComponents.getJsonContentsTextTask contentsTextTask =
        new UpdateComponents.getJsonContentsTextTask();
UpdateComponents.getJsonOtherContentsTextTask otherContentsTextTask =
        new UpdateComponents.getJsonOtherContentsTextTask();

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    contentsTextTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,
            "https://someurl.com");
    otherContentsTextTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,
            "https://anotherurl.com");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    RecyclerView recycler = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment,
            container, false);

    CaptionedImagesAdapter adapter = new CaptionedImagesAdapter(names, images);
    recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
    GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
    recycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    adapter.setListener(new CaptionedImagesAdapter.CardViewListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(int position) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AnotherActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(AnotherActivity.CONTENT, someContents.get(position));
            intent.putExtra(AnotherActivity.ANOTHER_CONTENT, anotherContents.get(position));
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return recycler;
}


@Override
public void passContentsResult(ArrayList<String> result) {
    someContents = new ArrayList<>(result);
}


@Override
public void passAnotherContentsResult(ArrayList<String> result) {
    anotherContents = new ArrayList<>(result);
}

}
```

The code for getting values from intent in the other activity:

```
public class AnotherActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final String CONTENT = "content";
public static final String ANOTHER_CONTENT = "anotherContent";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_another);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    TextView contents = findViewById(R.id.contents);
    TextView anotherContents = findViewById(R.id.anotherContents);

    contents.setText((CharSequence) getIntent().getExtras().get(CONTENT));
    anotherContent.setText((CharSequence) getIntent().getExtras().get(ANOTHER_CONTENT));
}
}
```

How to preserve the downloaded ArrayLists from AsyncTask, so I can pass it to the other activity? and is there any way to keep these ArrayLists preserved so if I returned back from the other activity I won't need to re-download it again?

Thanks for support in advance.

**UPDATE**
Using simple code I found same issue happening:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "DownloadData";
TextView tv;
ImageView imageView;
String text;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv = findViewById(R.id.TestTxt);
    String text = "sometext to text";
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: " + text);
}

public void onClick(View v){
    Log.d(TAG, "onClick: " + text);
    tv.setText(text);
}
```

When logging the value after being created in the onCreate it's ok, once click the Button to initiate onClick method, I found its value is null.

Comment: While I have an idea or two why you encounter an error, I'd like to make sure by setting up a small sample before answering. Unfortunately, your code is not complete (e.g. AsyncTask plus UpdateComponents.AsyncContentsResponse are missing). If I just patch it I might accidentally do everything correctly and so I would not be able to reproduce your problem. **TL;DR**: please share enough code so we can reproduce the error

Comment: @0X0nosugar Thanks for your response, please be informed that there's no issue with the AsyncTask that it's used to populate the names of cards in the RecycledView, also I checked using logd for the returned values of the contents ArrayList and it gives the proper response, however the issue as illustrated above; once the passContents method finished execution the ArrayList retained to null (which also checked before starting the intent).

Comment: Well, I understand if you're reluctant to dump your whole app here (and that's not what I was asking for anyway). And of course others may be able to help you without any further code snippets. But if this should not be the case then maybe you'll want to set up a small sample with the problem behavior (this would not even have to contain two lists etc.). I much prefer using a debugger to using a crystal ball ;-)

Comment: @0X0nosugar I took your advise and made a simple code and I found the same issue, here is the code:

Comment: public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "DownloadData";
    TextView tv;
    ImageView imageView;
    String text;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        tv = findViewById(R.id.TestTxt);
        String text = "sometext to text";
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: " + text);
    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: " + text);
        tv.setText(text);
    }

Comment: Well, this is not exactly the same issue. In your small sample, the field *text* is still null in onClick() because you used a local variable *text* in onCreate(). But you don't use a local variable for your ArrayLists, or do you?

Comment: It's defined as private variable in the class as listed in the code above...

Comment: So I'm sure you agree your "sample" isn't really about the same type of problem.

Comment: @0X0nosugar Thank you very much for your contribution, I found the problem cause was that I forgot to assign AsyncTask interface variable to the fragment instance of it:
(contentsTextTask.contentsResponse = this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem cause, that I forgot to assign AsyncTask interface variable to fragment instance of it:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  contentsTextTask.contentsResponse = this;
  contentsTextTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,
          "https://someurl.com");
  otherContentsTextTask.otherContentsResponse = this;
  otherContentsTextTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,
          "https://anotherurl.com");
}
```

Special Thanks to 0X0nosugar for his contribution and help.